# How to avoid black background areas when the app performs a screen rotation transition?

Tags: ios, ipad, transition

Seen from the Apple TV, and many other ipad apps, there are black corner areas when the apps perform screen transitions.

Here is the Apple TV app:

[image: 000000]

Here is the problematic transition:

[image: 000]

There is a black background area.

[image: 888]

How to improve this? How can I put a "global" background image?

This black area does not look like a normal Apple-like design; it is quite weird...